MSVC rejects delegating constructor using base class alias, adopted from the base class
The following code compiles with g++ 14.2 and clang++ 18.1, but fails with MSVC 17.10.
class Base {
public:
  using peak = Base;
  Base() = default;
};

class Derived : public Base {
protected:
  using Base::peak; 

public:
  Derived() : peak() { } // rejected by MSVC
};

int main() {
  Derived d1{};
}

MSVC errors:
error C2437: 'peak': has already been initialized
error C2437: 'peak': has already been initialized

Is the use of the peak alias valid C++?
Note: If we use using peak = Base::peak instead of using Base::peak, compilation succeeds with all three compilers.

MSVC rejects this while gcc and clang accept. Demo

@OP Note this is not a vscode problem but a compiler's problem(msvc)

Indenting your code correctly would be a good start. :/

This looks like a MSVC bug.

@HolyBlackCat I agree on the indenting part but I wonder if removing the language-lawyer tag was good. There is quite some language-lawyering already on SO around these parts so I wouldn't be surprised if a proper answer has to include some standardeze. I'm trying to dig up at least one occurance that I found lately (still failing though).

I would consider your use of the type-alias as rather unusual, and not something a beginner should come across. Where did you read about this usage of type-aliases? What underlying problem is it supposed to solve?

Sidenote: using peak = Base::peak; works in MSVC and all the others too.

Do we really need to language-lawyer this? There's no reason why this shouldn't compile, and the error message is nonsensical; looks like an obvious compiler bug to me.

@HolyBlackCat Perhaps not - but to motivate it as being a bug, perhaps. There was some clarification about the intent of how using declarations are supposed to work in some notes from the committee that I'm looking for. I'm doing a crap job at it though ...

Not sure what you intent to achieve with using Base::peak;. You can use peak already in the class scope without it (since the name is found in the base class) and because Base is inherited publicly, a user of Derived can still use peak anyway by writing Base::peak explicitly (or just Base for that matter).

@HolyBlackCat "looks like an obvious compiler bug to me..." Nothing is obvious in C++. Nothing.

Not related to your question per se: Don't use namespace std, that's a bad idea

Sidenote: Although this is a rather theoretical question (I can't find a practical reason for why anyone would want to do this), I think it's a good question.

The program is well-formed.This can be seen from class.base.init that explicitly allows this:

A mem-initializer-list can initialize a base class using any class-or-decltype that denotes that base class type.
[Example 1: 
struct A { A(); };
typedef A global_A;  <---------------------
struct B { };                             |
struct C: public A, public B { C(); };    |
                                          v
C::C(): global_A() { }                 // mem-initializer for base A
— end example]


Now class-or-decltype includes nested-name-specifieropt type-name where the optional nested-name-specifier_opt will be empty in our case and type-name includes typedef-name(which is peak) in our case.

Here is the newly submitted msvc bug:
MSVC rejects valid program involving using declaration for alias used in mem-initializer-list

Love it when answers go with a bugreport. +1 even without the bugreport :-)

It looks like MSVC tries to interpret that as Derived():Base(),peak() {} , and then fails to spot that Base and peak are same thing
